# How can one characterize categories of exact functors?

Tags: ct.category-theory, abelian-categories, short-exact-sequences

Does there exist any intrinsic characterization of additive categories equivalent to $\operatorname{Ex}(A,Ab)$, that is, of exact functors from a small abelian category $A$ into abelian groups? Any hints (including sufficient conditions) would be very welcome!

Comment: Have you seen this paper? Modules as exact functors, by M. Prest, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.08015.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much!  M. Prest has written several papers and books on these (definable) categories.